# ASP MVC Checkbox not clickable in chrome

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'm having an issue using HTML/Bootstrap inside a razor view.

I am using the bootstrap row/col div's for formatting. When I put a checkbox within a `div class="col-md-2"`, the checkbox is not clickable inside Google Chrome. However it does work in IE.

If I remove the `div class="col-md-2"`, the checkbox becomes clickable.

The project is using the default `Site.css` and `bootstrap.css` that is produced by visual studio.

Source:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"><input type="checkbox" id="checkall" value="checkall"><span>Check All</span></div>
    <div class="col-md-12"><input id="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-outline" value="+" onclick="AddParamAll();" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: On [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)'s website, when they provide examples of the grid system they say **Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases.**..  in your example your `btnAdd` has the max amount of col's with `col-md-12`.. what happens if you made the `btnAdd` to `col-md-10` and kept the checkbox as `col-md-10`? [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNBQyN)

Comment: Yup, that fixed it, thanks for you help

Comment: I added my answer, so if you could please mark it as accepted to let others know that it has been answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)'s website, when they provide examples of the grid system they say **Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases**... in your example your `btnAdd` has the max amount of col's with `col-md-12`.. what happens if you made the `btnAdd` to `col-md-10` and kept the checkbox as `col-md-10`?

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNBQyN)